# ceedling/cmock: mocking variadic functions, or va_list parameter

Tags: gcc, mocking, variadic, cmock, ceedling

I tried to mock this code:

```c
int myPrintf(const char *fmt, ...);
int myVprintf(const char *fmt, va_list args);
```

for both functions some wrong code is generated. For example:

```c
typedef int (* CMOCK_myPrintf_CALLBACK)(const char* fmt, int cmock_num_calls);
void myPrintf_AddCallback(CMOCK_myPrintf_CALLBACK Callback);
void myPrintf_Stub(CMOCK_myPrintf_CALLBACK Callback);
#define myPrintf_StubWithCallback myPrintf_Stub
```

Even, in the case of the `va_list` parameters, generated code does not compile:

```c
void CMockExpectParameters_myVprintf(CMOCK_myVprintf_CALL_INSTANCE* cmock_call_instance, const char* fmt, va_list args)
{
  cmock_call_instance->Expected_fmt = fmt;
  memcpy((void*)(&cmock_call_instance->Expected_args), (void*)(&args),
         sizeof(va_list[sizeof(args) == sizeof(va_list) ? 1 : -1])); /* add va_list to :treat_as_array if this causes an error */
}
```

Is there a way around these problems?

Comment: Can you post your yaml file along with your ceedling version? It's asking you to add va_list to the treat as array section.

Comment: @mastupristi Did you ever work this out?