# Ceedling/CMock: Adding va_list to :treat_as_array: produces a TypeError

Tags: c, unit-testing, embedded, cmock, ceedling

I am working on developing some unit tests for some non-open source inherited code. For now I have just been testing the ceedling framework, using the autogenerated tests to ensure everything runs as it should.

Everything works fine when I run tests for the modules with no dependencies, but when running a test for one of the modules with a bunch of dependencies (that I had to include as mocks):

```
#ifdef TEST

#include "unity.h"

#include "conn.h"
#include "mock_log.h"
#include "mock_memory.h"
#include "mock_rxbuffer.h"
#include "mock_txbuffer.h"


void setUp(void)
{
}

void tearDown(void)
{
}

void test_conn_NeedToImplement(void)
{
    TEST_IGNORE_MESSAGE("Need to Implement conn");
}

#endif // TEST
```

Ceedling encounters an error when mocking the following function:

```
void tx_push (struct txbuffer *tx, const char *format, va_list ap)
```

The error sais as follows:

```
Test 'test_conn.c'
------------------
Generating runner for test_conn.c...
Compiling test_conn_runner.c...
Compiling mock_txbuffer.c...
build/test/mocks/mock_txbuffer.c: In function ‘CMockExpectParameters_tx_push’:
build/test/mocks/mock_txbuffer.c:420:31: warning: ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘ap’ will return size of ‘__va_list_tag *’ [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
          sizeof(va_list[sizeof(ap) == sizeof(va_list) ? 1 : -1])); /* add va_list to :treat_as_array if this causes an error */
                               ^
build/test/mocks/mock_txbuffer.c:414:149: note: declared here
 void CMockExpectParameters_tx_push(CMOCK_tx_push_CALL_INSTANCE* cmock_call_instance, struct txbuffer* tx, int tx_Depth, const char* format, va_list ap)
                                                                                                                                                     ^~
build/test/mocks/mock_txbuffer.c:420:24: error: size of unnamed array is negative
          sizeof(va_list[sizeof(ap) == sizeof(va_list) ? 1 : -1])); /* add va_list to :treat_as_array if this causes an error */
                        ^
ERROR: Shell command failed.
```

So as suggested by the message I added `va_list` to `:treat_as_array` :

```
:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :array
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8
  :treat_as_array:
      - va_list
  :includes:
    - <assert.h>
    - <getopt.h>
    - <libgen.h>
    - <stdbool.h>
    - <stdint.h>
    - <stdio.h>
    - <stdlib.h>
    - <string.h>
```

After doing this I ended up getting a **new error** (running ceedling in debug) in the form of:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

```
** Invoke test:conn (first_time)
** Invoke test/test_conn.c (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute test:conn
** Invoke test_deps (first_time)
** Invoke directories (first_time)
** Invoke build/test/mocks (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/artifacts (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/artifacts/test (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/runners (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/results (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/out (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/out/asm (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/out/c (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/cache (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/dependencies (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/logs (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/temp (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/preprocess/includes (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/test/preprocess/files (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/gcov/out (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/gcov/results (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/gcov/dependencies (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke build/artifacts/gcov (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute directories
** Execute test_deps


Test 'test_conn.c'
------------------
Verbose: exec(): gcc -E -MM -MG -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "build/temp/_test_conn.c"
> Shell executed command:
'gcc -E -MM -MG -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "build/temp/_test_conn.c"'
> Produced output:
_test_conn.o: build/temp/_test_conn.c \
 /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity.h \
 /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src/unity_internals.h \
 @@@@unity.h src/conn.h @@@@conn.h mock_log.h @@@@mock_log.h \
 mock_memory.h @@@@mock_memory.h mock_rxbuffer.h @@@@mock_rxbuffer.h \
 mock_txbuffer.h @@@@mock_txbuffer.h

** Invoke build/test/preprocess/includes/log.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke src/log.h (first_time, not_needed)
Verbose: exec(): gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/log.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/log.h"
> Shell executed command:
'gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/log.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/log.h"'

** Invoke build/test/preprocess/includes/memory.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke src/memory.h (first_time, not_needed)
Verbose: exec(): gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/memory.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/memory.h"
> Shell executed command:
'gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/memory.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/memory.h"'

** Invoke build/test/preprocess/includes/rxbuffer.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke src/rxbuffer.h (first_time, not_needed)
Verbose: exec(): gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/rxbuffer.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/rxbuffer.h"
> Shell executed command:
'gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/rxbuffer.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/rxbuffer.h"'

** Invoke build/test/preprocess/includes/txbuffer.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Invoke src/txbuffer.h (first_time, not_needed)
Verbose: exec(): gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/txbuffer.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/txbuffer.h"
> Shell executed command:
'gcc -E -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/unity/src" -I"/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"src" -DTEST -DTEST -DGNU_COMPILER "src/txbuffer.h" -o "build/test/preprocess/files/txbuffer.h"'

** Invoke build/test/mocks/mock_log.c (first_time)
** Invoke build/test/cache/log.h (first_time, not_needed)
** Execute build/test/mocks/mock_log.c
Creating mock for log...
rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:421:in `block in parse_args'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:411:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:411:in `parse_args'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:588:in `parse_declaration'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:45:in `block in parse'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:44:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock_header_parser.rb:44:in `parse'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock.rb:48:in `generate_mock'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock.rb:32:in `block in setup_mocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock.rb:31:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/vendor/cmock/lib/cmock.rb:31:in `setup_mocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/generator.rb:50:in `generate_mock'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/rules_cmock.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/task_invoker.rb:60:in `block in invoke_test_mocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/task_invoker.rb:58:in `invoke_test_mocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/preprocessinator.rb:28:in `preprocess_test_and_invoke_test_mocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:84:in `block in setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:51:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:51:in `setup_and_invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/lib/ceedling/rules_tests.rake:70:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:345:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/ceedling-0.31.1/bin/ceedling:332:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/ceedling:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build/test/mocks/mock_log.c
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

--------------------
OVERALL TEST SUMMARY
--------------------

No tests executed.
```

If I remove `va_list` from `:treat_as_array` I can succesfully test modules with dependencies, as long as they do not have functions that take `va_list` as an input. Otherwise I still get the same error even if there are no `va_list` functions:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

So it seems to me that there could be an issue with the way I include `va_list` to `:treat_as_array`?

Reaching this point I was more of less out of ideas on what to try. I have also opened an [issue on the github for ceedling](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/issues/689) stating this very problem, but I'm hoping to get some input from other ceedling users that might have encountered this problem too.

My ceedling version is the following (Ubuntu 18.04.2):

```
   Ceedling:: 0.31.1
      Unity:: 2.5.4
      CMock:: 2.5.4
 CException:: 1.3.3
```

There is a similar question in stack exchange that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66832992/ceedling-cmock-mocking-variadic-functions-or-va-list-parameter), but whithout the extra step of adding `va_list` to `:treat_as_array`.

And there are several github issues talking about the lack of support for variatic functions:

- https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/397
- https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/204
- https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CMock/issues/129

**So I guess I just want to figure out whether this is an unsupported feature or wether im doing something wrong.**

Any help will be gratly appreaciated.

Best regards,
GCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I was adding the va_list wrongly.

It needs to be :

```
  :treat_as_array:
    va_list
```

Now cmock is no longer complaining about the mocked module.

I couldnt find any examples of how to add something to :treat_as_array:, so hopefully this helps.